# IntelliJ Search and Replace Ignore Newline

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to search in IntelliJ with Find & Replace a small piece of code, that might or might not be split into multiple lines. After or before each dot there might be a newline. I was thinking to use a regex like this, but it didn't work.

`org[\r\n]?.[\r\n]?apache[\r\n]?.[\r\n]?log4j[\r\n]?.[\r\n]?Logger[\r\n]?.[\r\n]?getEffectiveLevel()`

=> org.apache.log4j.Logger.getEffectiveLevel()

`\r\n` for Carridge Return + New Line

Comment: Can't you do a Find Usages on the `getEffectiveLevel()` method?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers Sorry, it was just an example. I do have many more cases where it is not as distinguishable as here.